# Jquery and Table Manipulation

Tags: php, jquery

I have a created a table through looping in php. i.e. number of rows in table will be dynamic(1,2,3,4,5 etc. as i want to display).
I want that in each row at last td, when we focus then all previous td's values will be calculated and will be shown in last td.

```
<select name="number" id="number"  onchange="document.form2.submit()">
<? for($j=1;$j<=5;$j++) {?>
    <option value="<?=$j ?>" <?=($j==$_REQUEST['number'])?'selected':'' ?>><?=$j ?></option>
<? } $num=$_REQUEST['number']; ?>
</select>
<table width="100%" border="0"  cellpadding="4" cellspacing="5" id="mytable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="35%">Length</th>
            <th width="36%">Width</th>
            <th width="29%">Area</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <? for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++) {?>
        <tr class="row">
            <td><input type="text" name="length" class="textbox" id="length"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="width" class="textbox" id="width" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="area" class="textbox" id="area" onfocus="" /></td>
        </tr>
    <? } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

please provide the code to select last td of each row.
i have tried much but not succeeded yet.All help will be appreciated...

Comment: what do you mean by focus? focus is something you do to input elements. If you mean "on click" then what is displayed before you click? Is there a reason you aren't just calculating the "area" in php and putting it in the html?

Comment: have a look http://cssglobe.com/lab/tablecloth/

Answer (score 0):

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ptCpk/)

```
$(function() {

    $('input[name="area"]').on('focus', function() {
        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var $length = $tr.find('input[name="length"]').val();
        var $width = $tr.find('input[name="width"]').val();
        this.value = $length * $width
    });

});​
```

by the way, IDs can only be used once. you can't use it multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

To select the last `td` of the row

```
$('tr.row td:last-child');
```

To select the `textbox` in the last `td` of the row:

```
$('tr.row td:last-child').children('input.textbox')​
```

To make this a lot easier, don't repeat IDs on the page and put additional classes in your textboxes:

```
<? for($i=0; $i<$num; $i++) {?>
<tr class="row">
    <td><input type="text" name="length" class="textbox length" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="width" class="textbox width" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="area" class="textbox area" onfocus="" /></td>
</tr>
<? } ?>
```

With your markup as above, to select the `textbox` in the last `td` of the row becomes:

```
$('input.area')​
```